# SQL Server: How to put indirectly connected data into the same table, field for analysis (count)?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I created a query (SQL Server) that counts the amount of times a particular part of a form is not filled out. I was able to successfully do this, but the trouble is I want to compare the count of the part of the form not being filled out with the count of times it was filled out.

I was able to get both of these counts. The trouble is putting them together. I'm basically trying to get a percentage of the times the part was filled out.

I have something like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
fa.FormID
INTO #temp
FROM FormAnswers fa
JOIN FormQuestions fq ON fa.FormQuestionID =          fq.FormQuestionID
WHERE fq.FormQuestion = 'question 21'

SELECT 
c.CustomerName, c.CustomerState, f.FormDate
FROM customers c
JOIN Forms f ON f.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
JOIN FormQuestions fq On fq.FormID = f.FormID
WHERE fa.FormID NOT IN (SELECT * FROM #temp)
```

So, this gives me all the customers who didn't fill out that question on the form, but how can I better incorporate that with all the customers who did —putting them in the same table, a field saying 'Filled out' or 'Not filled out', which I can then use as a count.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide sample data and desired results?  It is not clear what results you want.

Comment: Hint: you can replace the `SELECT * FROM #temp` in your second query with your entire first query

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
   SELECT 
        c.CustomerName, c.CustomerState, f.FormDate
    FROM 
        customers c
    JOIN 
        Forms f 
    ON 
        f.CustomerID = c.CustomerID
    JOIN 
        FormQuestions fq 
    On 
        fq.FormID = f.FormID
    JOIN 
        FormAnswers fa 
    On 
        fa.FormQuestionID = fq.FormQuestionID
    WHERE 
        fa.FormID NOT IN (SELECT * FROM #temp)
    AND 
        fq.FormQuestion = 'question 21'
```